# SQL Statement as datasource for listbox VB.NET

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, listbox

ok so I got a listbox which I made the displaymember equal to "ID"

I fill my dataset and if I make a change to my dataset the listbox will change also.

I'm filling my dataset with this kind of dataAdapter :

KamersDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID FROM roomsTable", ConnectionString)

So far so good.

It would be cool if I could make an nice sentence So the user could read something nice in the listbox then just the database items. So I did this :

```
New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT *, convert(varchar,convert(date,StartDatum),103) +' - ' + convert(varchar,convert(date,EindDatum),103) + ': room ' + convert(varchar,KamerNummer) AS combinatie FROM VerhuringenTable", ConnectionString)
```

then instead of putting the displaymember to ID, I put it to Combinatie (dutch for combination)

Now if i fill my dataset for the first times everything goes fine. Then I get this:

```
18/01/2014-30/05/2014:room 103
```

But now when i Add an new room. the room doesnt want to show up in my listbox.
with other words...my dataset is not updating or my listbox cant handle this query

I know it HAS to do with this sql statement cause my listbox updates fine when i Just select The ID.

Anyone knows whats goin on ?

thanx

fosa

Comment: Add item to DB then rerun query.

Comment: I don't want the data in my database. I want it in my dataset. I want the data in my database when I finnally sync the DB with the dataset...which is a diffrent button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column `combinatie` is calculated at the extraction of your data from the database. After that the Dataset doesn't contains any rules that could be applied at runtime to generate the `combinatie` column from the data of the new Room.
You should add the info for this field manually to the dataset table,
probably when you add the booking for the Room

```
 Dim newRow = ds.Tables("room").NewRow()
 newRow("StartDatum") = DateTime.Today
 newRow("EindDatum") = DateTime.Today.AddDays(7)
 newRow("KamerNummer") = roomNumber
 ....
 newRow("combinatie") = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() & "-" & _ 
                        DateTime.Today.AddDays(7).ToShortDateString() & _ 
                        ":room " & roomNumber.ToString()
ds.Tables("room").Rows.Add(newRow)
```

Comment: Ofcourse! how could I be so stupid. The column combination is indeed build after the extraction. The dataset doent know of anything...Thanx Steve!